# Resident in the Netherlands, remotely working for US company. Do I need any visa?

Tags: working-visas, netherlands

I live and I'm resident in the Netherlands, and I'm interested in some remote jobs from US. My nationality is Italian.

1. Do I need any visa or work permit?
2. Do I pay taxes in US? (in Netherlands for sure)
3. What if I'm freelancer and I get a client in US?

Comment: Are you referring to possibly needing a visa or work permit from UK or US?

Comment: @Traveller yes exactly. If I need any VISA from the country with the job, even if I reside in the netherlands

Comment: Just to be clear: you are not planning on actually traveling to the US (or UK), correct?

Comment: @MikeHarris No. That's why I wrote "remote" job. Remote from Netherlands.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @David Italian.

Comment: Please don't write "visa" in all caps.

Comment: What kind of contractual relationship do you have with the US company? Are you an employee? A consultant? Service provider?

Comment: If you have clients in the UK, it is very likely that you will need to charge them VAT (value added tax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're not physically traveling to the US, you don't need a US visa. However, whatever work you undertake while in the Netherlands must comport with whatever work type or other requirements or restrictions the Dutch government might impose, if any, on non-Dutch residents.
2. Because you're not working physically in the US, and are not a US citizen, you are not required to file a US income tax return, nor are you obligated to pay US taxes. You will be liable for tax to the Netherlands.
3. See both answers above. If you wish to travel to the US, however, you may need a visa depending upon the purpose of your visit.
4. I'm not familiar with the UK tax system, and don't know if, as a non-UK resident working remotely for a UK firm, you'd be liable for UK taxes. Because the UK is not within the Schengen area, your ability to travel to the UK will be determined by your nationality and the purpose of your visit. [This UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa?step-by-step-nav=d8f3c2e0-d544-4664-9616-ab71323e4d18) has an answer-the-questions wizard to answer the "do I need a visa?" question.

Comment: If an employee recruited overseas is not resident in the UK, generally no PAYE is due unless the non-resident employee performs duties in the UK which are more than incidental to their overseas work. ‘Incidental duties’ are subordinate or ancillary to overseas work, such as training in the UK or general meetings. https://www.hrzone.com/perform/people/employing-people-overseas-tax-and-social-security-considerations

Comment: @Traveller That sounds like an answer to the tax part of the OP’s fourth question.

Comment: OP is an Italian citizen, so enjoys a virtually unrestricted right to work in the Netherlands and to travel to the UK.  The latter will be more restricted at some point if the UK leaves the EU.